# Junk characters in HTML - Google Cloud

Tags: html

Some of the HTML pages (which I migrated to a google cloud compute VM instance using Centos apache) show junk characters, the same HTML seen in my old server (Centos Apache) is fine. I have tried different file transfer modes, Auto, Binary, ASCII, none works any ideas what may be causing this? See images

[snapshot of html from both servers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCCr9.jpg)

Comment: Did you add `UTF-8` encoding in the `<head>` of your webpages?

Comment: The head tag did not help but your comment did lead me towards the correct direction, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted by using the following command, although it was tedious but did the job. Was unable to find a solution through FTP clients, changing encoding etc. but on the host the command worked and issue was resolved.

```sh
iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8//TRANSLIT input.file -o out.file
```